# Where precisely is topology required to prove the existence of non-zero eigenstates in the proof of the spectral theorem?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

My professor today remarked that the proof of the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) (even for the discrete spectrum case) uses not just algebra but also topology to prove the *existence* of eigenstates. However, I'm not being able to pinpoint which step of the proof of the spectral theorem (for infinite-dimensional operators) invokes topological arguments. Could someone please explain?

Comment: Most of the basic theory uses completeness in some way.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown In what sense is completeness a topological argument? (Not objecting; just curious.) Also, could you give an example of a step in the proof(s) of spectral that use(s) completeness?

Comment: Spectral theorem uses topology even in its statement. This theorem is about self adjoint operators. Adjoint operator can be defined only for densely-defined operators. Density is a topological term.

Comment: @Matsmir Yes, but here we are talking precisely about the proof of the existence of non-zero eigenstates and not the spectral theorem in its entirety

Comment: My guess is that any proof of [The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) must use topology.

Comment: For the finite dimensional case, look at the first paragraph of page 3 of [these notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/spectral.pdf) (which I found from a web search on "Spectral Theorem"); the argument boils down to the statement of the Extreme Value Theorem: Every continuous real valued function on a compact space has a maximum value. For the infinite dimensional case, as you wade through the messier technicalities, you can keep your eyes open for a similar argument.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least you need to establish that the spectrum is nonempty. This usually requires the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra in the finite-dimensional case, or some form of Liouville's Theorem in the general case. Examples:

- Theorem VII.3.6 in Conway's *A Course in Functional Analysis*.
- Theorem 1.2.5 in Murphy's *C$^*$-Algebras and Operator Theory*
- Theorem 3.2.3 in Kadison-Ringrose's *Fundamentals of Theory of Operator Algebras*
- Theorem 4.1.13 in Pedersen's *Analysis Now*
- Lemma VII.3.4.4 in Dumford-Schwartz *Linear Operators*

Comment: Some reference would be appreciated showing the usage of Liouville's theorem...

Comment: It appears in basically every functional analysis book. I added the references from the ones I had most at hand.